# Unity : Destroy a GameObject that is part of a prefab

Tags: unity-game-engine, destroy, gameobject, prefab

The console shows me this error :

`Cannot destroy GameObject that is part of a prefab instance. UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)`

I'm confused. The Logs don't tell which prefab or GameObject is involved.
Can u help me ?

Thanks a lot for answers !

Comment: Similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60236813/how-can-i-destroy-a-gameobject-that-is-part-of-a-prefab

Answer (score 0):

Many times when you edit prefabs you will notice that some of them can be blue, while others are with no color. The blue means that they maintain the reference to the original prefab in the project and that they are not a copy, so any change made to them wil be done to the original prefab itself, so the original prebab from which the copies (clones) are made from.

To avoid this, you need to [unpack](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnpackingPrefabInstances.html) the prefabs, so that you manipulate the copy instead of the original reference.

Probably the error is due to the fact that you are destroying some prefab that is not unpacked, so not destroyable by the runtime [GameObject.Destroy](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) that is to destroy a cloned copy from the scene.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you trying to destroy part of the prefab that is not instanced to the scene. If you need to modify some prefab in editor scripts please refer to [PrefabUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.html) but be aware that this class is accessible only from UnityEditor.

Otherwise please double check your code maybe you using the wrong reference to object after prefab instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue recently. A nested prefab was missing in one of the prefabs. Happened when an old prefab was deleted. Check your scene for "Missing Prefab"